# Displaying 4th slide in javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have been working on a javascript program that uses a slideshow to show different elements. As of right now, my program correctly displays 3 slides correctly but does not display the fourth one. I am still stumped as to why it is doing this.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var points = 5;
  points++;
  $("#draggable").draggable();


  $("#droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("second_class")
        .find("p")
        .html(alert(points--));
    }
  });
  $("#droppable2").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)

      .find("p")

      .html(alert(points++));

    },

    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable").droppable("disable")

    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable").droppable("enable")

    }


  });
});
$(function() {
  var points = 5;
  points++;
  $("#draggable2").draggable();


  $("#droppable3").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("second_class")
        .find("p")
        .html(alert(points--));
    }
  });
  $("#droppable4").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)

      .find("p")

      .html(alert(points++));

    },

    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable3").droppable("disable")

    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable3").droppable("enable")

    }


  });
});
$(function() {
  var points = 5;
  points++;
  $("#draggable5").draggable();


  $("#droppable6").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("second_class")
        .find("p")
        .html(alert(points--));
    }
  });
  $("#droppable6").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)

      .find("p")

      .html(alert(points++));

    },

    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable5").droppable("disable")

    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      $("#droppable5").droppable("enable")

    }


  });
});

$("#open_popup").click(function() {
  $("#popup").css("display", "block");
  
});

$("#close_popup").click(function() {
  $("#popup").css("display", "none");
});
$("#open_popup2").click(function() {
  $("#popup2").css("display", "block");
  
});

$("#close_popup2").click(function() {
  $("#popup2").css("display", "none");
});
$("#open_popup3").click(function() {
  $("#popup2").css("display", "block");
  
});

$("#close_popup3").click(function() {
  $("#popup2").css("display", "none");
});

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }


  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}

var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function pauseSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
  playing = false;
  clearInterval(slideIndex);
}

function playSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
  playing = true;

  setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reinhardt_scott/rA4CB/186/)

Comment: Please provide your code in your post, see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Only include code that is relevant to specific problem. All your draggables and miscellaneous event handlers have no relevance and should be removed

Comment: Sorry all I meant to post was the link to the js fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/reinhardt_scott/rA4CB/187/

Comment: @charlietfl I posted everything because I am not sure where the error is in the program.

Comment: HTML errors. There is an end body tag at line 31 but worse when I compact slide 3 in an HTML editor, slide 4 is hidden: indicating the div for slide4 is inside slilde 3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not showing is that the divs have not been ordered properly such that your third "mySlides" div actually contains your fourth one. Hence when you set the fourth div to be display:block, it won't show up.

I have removed all the click handlers and things like that and you can see it working in the fiddle below. A suggestion for the future would be to change the images so that they are all visually distinct as i think your third and fourth image look very similar.

Another tip is to move the document.getElementsByClassName selectors outside your function so that you only do it once as they are slow to perform.

As you are using jquery already...Why not use a jquery carousel?
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/189/

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if(i !== slideIndex){
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    } else{
        slides[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}
```